# How do you convert a DataTable into a generic list?

Tags: c#, generics, datatable

Currently, I'm using:

```
DataTable dt = CreateDataTableInSomeWay();

List<DataRow> list = new List<DataRow>(); 
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    list.Add(dr);
}
```

Is there a better/magic way?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with a List that you can't do with your DataRowCollection?

Comment: Mine is late but hope will be useful. Working solution..https://stackoverflow.com/a/58607820/9048996

Answer (score 304, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5, you can use [`DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) (an extension method) and then if you really need a `List<DataRow>` instead of just `IEnumerable<DataRow>` you can call [`Enumerable.ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> sequence = dt.AsEnumerable();
```

or

```
using System.Linq;
...
List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Comment: how to convert this `list` to json.

Comment: @Pandiya: There are various ways of converting data into JSON in .NET. Personally I've always used the JSON.NET library, but there are other approaches too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482261/how-to-convert-c-generic-list-to-json-using-json-net

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I want to get the value in DataRow. Is there any method? Instead of getting like list.ItemArray[0].

Comment: @Jon, FYI : dt.AsEnumerable().ToList()'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'

Comment: @BabekoofCoder: Then you need `using System.Linq;` as normal for LINQ. It should be fine at that point. (I've added that into the answer.)

Comment: what if I want to convert it into a generic list of my custom type? `List<MyType> = ?? ` Can this be done ?

Comment: Is there a version of this for UWP?  I can't get using system.data.DataSetExtensions in a UWP app... or DataTableExtensions

Comment: @Allstar: I haven't used UWP for doing anything with DataTables, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JonSkeet , thanks though I just got to it. Add the System.Data.DataSetExtensions nuget package... it then falls under the, already referenced, system.data namespace... which got me/confused

Comment: .AsEnumerable() exists in .net core 2.0 and above. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949302/linq-to-dataset-datatable-asenumerable-not-recognized

Comment: @Sponsor: Yes, but not in .NET 3.0 and below - .NET Core 2.0 came *much* later than .NET 3.5. Note that this answer was written in 2008.

Answer (score 71):

```
List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>();

//Maintaining DataTable on ViewState
//For Demo only

DataTable dt = ViewState["CurrentEmp"] as DataTable;

//read data from DataTable 
//using lamdaexpression


emp = (from DataRow row in dt.Rows

   select new Employee
   {
       _FirstName = row["FirstName"].ToString(),
       _LastName = row["Last_Name"].ToString()

   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Above code may not work bcs. dt.Rows has not implemented 'AsEnumerable'. This can be corrected as below:


 emp = (from DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable()

   select new Employee
   {
       _FirstName = row["FirstName"].ToString(),
       _LastName = row["Last_Name"].ToString()

   }).ToList();

Answer (score 44):

With C# 3.0 and System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll,

```
List<DataRow> rows = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
```

Comment: doing this has helped performance from just using a foreach over a datarow by 50% time.

Answer (score 37):

You could use

```
List<DataRow> list = new List<DataRow>(dt.Select());
```

`dt.Select()` will return all rows in your table, as an array of datarows, and the `List` constructor accepts that array of objects as an argument to initially fill your list with.

Comment: Select() doesn't need any parameters.  The parameterless overload would return all rows.

Answer (score 18):

You can create a extension function as :

```
public static List<T> ToListof<T>(this DataTable dt)
{
    const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
    var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
        .Select(c => c.ColumnName)
        .ToList();
    var objectProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(flags);
    var targetList = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow =>
    {
        var instanceOfT = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        foreach (var properties in objectProperties.Where(properties => columnNames.Contains(properties.Name) && dataRow[properties.Name] != DBNull.Value))
        {
            properties.SetValue(instanceOfT, dataRow[properties.Name], null);
        }
        return instanceOfT;
    }).ToList();

    return targetList;
}


var output = yourDataInstance.ToListof<targetModelType>();
```

Comment: Doesn't work - see https://dotnetfiddle.net/I22r2c

It should also be noted that using Reflection is slow and not reccomended in performance critical code.

Comment: You need to add data type information for columns.                               
               DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("id",typeof(Int32 ));
  dt.Columns.Add("name",typeof(String));
  dt.Columns.Add("foo",typeof(DateTime ));
  for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++){dt.Rows.Add(i, "foo", DateTime.Now);}

Answer (score 17):

If you just want a list of values from the "ID" int field returned, you could use...

```
List<int> ids = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable() select Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 15):

I have added some modification to the code from this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24588210/4489664) because for nullable Types it will return exception

```
public static List<T> DataTableToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T: new()
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    var typeProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(propertyInfo => new
        {
            PropertyInfo = propertyInfo,
            Type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType) ?? propertyInfo.PropertyType
        }).ToList();

    foreach (var row in table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
    {
        T obj = new T();
        foreach (var typeProperty in typeProperties)
        {
            object value = row[typeProperty.PropertyInfo.Name];
            object safeValue = value == null || DBNull.Value.Equals(value)
                ? null
                : Convert.ChangeType(value, typeProperty.Type);

            typeProperty.PropertyInfo.SetValue(obj, safeValue, null);
        }
        list.Add(obj);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I removed the class because it can work with struct too.

Comment: This works pretty well, good job.  If anyone wants to play around with the code, I created a .net fiddle at this link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mTKevy

Comment: @Almenon I have added small modification, it should a bit increase performance

Answer (score 11):

```
using System.Data;


var myEnumerable = myDataTable.AsEnumerable();

List<MyClass> myClassList =
    (from item in myEnumerable
     select new MyClass{
         MyClassProperty1 = item.Field<string>("DataTableColumnName1"),
         MyClassProperty2 = item.Field<string>("DataTableColumnName2")
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

Again, using 3.5 you may do it like:

```
dt.Select().ToList()
```

BRGDS

Answer (score 6):

```
// this is better suited for expensive object creation/initialization
IEnumerable<Employee> ParseEmployeeTable(DataTable dtEmployees)
{
    var employees = new ConcurrentBag<Employee>();

    Parallel.ForEach(dtEmployees.AsEnumerable(), (dr) =>
    {
        employees.Add(new Employee() 
        {
            _FirstName = dr["FirstName"].ToString(),
            _LastName = dr["Last_Name"].ToString()
        });
    });

    return employees;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**The Easiest way of Converting the DataTable into the Generic list of class**

using Newtonsoft.Json;

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable);
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClassName>>(json);
```

Answer (score 5):

A more 'magic' way, and doesn't need .NET 3.5.

If, for example, `DBDatatable` was returning a single column of Guids (uniqueidentifier in SQL) then you could use:

```
Dim gList As New List(Of Guid)
gList.AddRange(DirectCast(DBDataTable.Select(), IEnumerable(Of Guid)))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DataTable dt;   // datatable should contains datacolumns with Id,Name

List<Employee> employeeList=new List<Employee>();  // Employee should contain  EmployeeId, EmployeeName as properties

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    employeeList.Add(new Employee{EmployeeId=dr.Id,EmplooyeeName=dr.Name});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`DataTable.Select()` doesnt give the Rows in the order they were present in the datatable.

If order is important I feel iterating over the datarow collection and forming a List is the right way to go or you could also use overload of `DataTable.Select(string filterexpression, string sort)`.

But this overload may not handle all the ordering (like order by case ...) that SQL provides.

Answer (score 2):

```
        /* This is a generic method that will convert any type of DataTable to a List 
         * 
         * 
         * Example :    List< Student > studentDetails = new List< Student >();  
         *              studentDetails = ConvertDataTable< Student >(dt);  
         *
         * Warning : In this case the DataTable column's name and class property name
         *           should be the same otherwise this function will not work properly
         */
```

> The following are the two functions in which if we pass a
>   DataTable 
>                and a user defined class. 
>                It will then return the List of that class with the DataTable data.

```
        public static List<T> ConvertDataTable<T>(DataTable dt)
        {
            List<T> data = new List<T>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                T item = GetItem<T>(row);
                data.Add(item);
            }
            return data;
        }


        private static T GetItem<T>(DataRow dr)
        {
            Type temp = typeof(T);
            T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

            foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Table.Columns)
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo pro in temp.GetProperties())
                {
                   //in case you have a enum/GUID datatype in your model
                   //We will check field's dataType, and convert the value in it.
                    if (pro.Name == column.ColumnName){                
                    try
                    {
                        var convertedValue = GetValueByDataType(pro.PropertyType, dr[column.ColumnName]);
                        pro.SetValue(obj, convertedValue, null);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {         
                       //ex handle code                   
                        throw;
                    }
                        //pro.SetValue(obj, dr[column.ColumnName], null);
                }
                    else
                        continue;
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }
```

> This method will check the datatype of field, and convert dataTable value in to that datatype.

```
    private static object GetValueByDataType(Type propertyType, object o)
    {
        if (o.ToString() == "null")
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (propertyType == (typeof(Guid)) || propertyType == typeof(Guid?))
        {
            return Guid.Parse(o.ToString());
        }
        else if (propertyType == typeof(int) || propertyType.IsEnum) 
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(o);
        }
        else if (propertyType == typeof(decimal) )
        {
            return Convert.ToDecimal(o);
        }
        else if (propertyType == typeof(long))
        {
            return Convert.ToInt64(o);
        }
        else if (propertyType == typeof(bool) || propertyType == typeof(bool?))
        {
            return Convert.ToBoolean(o);
        }
        else if (propertyType == typeof(DateTime) || propertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
        {
            return Convert.ToDateTime(o);
        }
        return o.ToString();
    }
```

> To call the preceding method, use the following syntax:

```
List< Student > studentDetails = new List< Student >();  
studentDetails = ConvertDataTable< Student >(dt);
```

> Change the Student class name and dt value based on your requirements. In this case the DataTable column's name and class property name should be the same otherwise this function will not work properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be great if you would also add a short explanation and a few comments to your code. This helps people to understand your answer better.

Answer (score 2):

```
lPerson = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(s => new Person()
        {
            Name = s.Field<string>("Name"),
            SurName = s.Field<string>("SurName"),
            Age = s.Field<int>("Age"),
            InsertDate = s.Field<DateTime>("InsertDate")
        }).ToList();
```

Link to working [DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jPozFN)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;   
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;

    public static void Main()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("SurName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("InsertDate", typeof(DateTime));

        var row1= dt.NewRow();
        row1["Name"] = "Adam";
        row1["SurName"] = "Adam";
        row1["Age"] = 20;
        row1["InsertDate"] = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
        dt.Rows.Add(row1);

        var row2 = dt.NewRow();
        row2["Name"] = "John";
        row2["SurName"] = "Smith";
        row2["Age"] = 25;
        row2["InsertDate"] = new DateTime(2020, 3, 12);
        dt.Rows.Add(row2);

        var row3 = dt.NewRow();
        row3["Name"] = "Jack";
        row3["SurName"] = "Strong";
        row3["Age"] = 32;
        row3["InsertDate"] = new DateTime(2020, 5, 20);
        dt.Rows.Add(row3);

        List<Person> lPerson = new List<Person>();
        lPerson = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(s => new Person()
        {
            Name = s.Field<string>("Name"),
            SurName = s.Field<string>("SurName"),
            Age = s.Field<int>("Age"),
            InsertDate = s.Field<DateTime>("InsertDate")
        }).ToList();
        
        foreach(Person pers in lPerson)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", pers.Name, pers.SurName, pers.Age, pers.InsertDate);
        }
    }   
    
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SurName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Data` namespace then you will get `.AsEnumerable()`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a Generic Method for converting `DataTable` to `List` instead of manually converting a `DataTable` to `List`.

Note: `DataTable`'s `ColumnName` and `Type`'s `PropertyName` should be same.

Call the below Method:

```
long result = Utilities.ConvertTo<Student>(dt ,out listStudent);

// Generic Method
public class Utilities
{
    public static long ConvertTo<T>(DataTable table, out List<T> entity)
    {
        long returnCode = -1;
        entity = null;

        if (table == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        try
        {
            entity = ConvertTo<T>(table.Rows);
            returnCode = 0;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            returnCode = 1000;
        }

        return returnCode;
    }

    static List<T> ConvertTo<T>(DataRowCollection rows)
    {
        List<T> list = null;
        if (rows != null)
        {
            list = new List<T>();

            foreach (DataRow row in rows)
            {
                T item = CreateItem<T>(row);
                list.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    static T CreateItem<T>(DataRow row)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        string strObj = string.Empty;

        T obj = default(T);

        if (row != null)
        {
            obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            strObj = obj.ToString();
            NameValueCollection objDictionary = new NameValueCollection();

            foreach (DataColumn column in row.Table.Columns)
            {
                PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(column.ColumnName);

                if (prop != null)
                {
                    str = column.ColumnName;

                    try
                    {
                        objDictionary.Add(str, row[str].ToString());
                        object value = row[column.ColumnName];
                        Type vType = obj.GetType();

                        if (value == DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            if (vType == typeof(int) || vType == typeof(Int16)
                                                     || vType == typeof(Int32)
                                                     || vType == typeof(Int64)
                                                     || vType == typeof(decimal)
                                                     || vType == typeof(float)
                                                     || vType == typeof(double))
                            {
                                value = 0;
                            }

                            else if (vType == typeof(bool))
                            {
                                value = false;
                            }

                            else if (vType == typeof(DateTime))
                            {
                                value = DateTime.MaxValue;
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                value = null;
                            }

                            prop.SetValue(obj, value, null);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(obj, value, null);
                        }
                    }

                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

            PropertyInfo ActionProp = obj.GetType().GetProperty("ActionTemplateValue");

            if (ActionProp != null)
            {
                object ActionValue = objDictionary;
                ActionProp.SetValue(obj, ActionValue, null);
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone want's to create custom function to convert datatable to list

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable table = GetDataTable();
        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();
        LinqMethod(table);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time for Linq Method={0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw.Reset();

        sw.Start();
        ForEachMethod(table);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time for Foreach method={0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static DataTable GetDataTable()
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(double));
        table.Columns.Add("CategoryName", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Active", typeof(double));

        var rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(i, "name" + i,  rand.Next(0, 2));
        }
        return table;
    }

    private static void LinqMethod(DataTable table)
    {
        var list = table.AsEnumerable()
            .Skip(1)
            .Select(dr =>
                new Category
                {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Field<double>("ID")),
                    CategoryName = dr.Field<string>("CategoryName"),                      
                    IsActive =
                            dr.Field<double>("Active") == 1 ? true : false
                }).ToList();
    }
    private static void ForEachMethod(DataTable table)
    {
        var categoryList = new List<Category>(table.Rows.Count);
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            var values = row.ItemArray;
            var category = new Category()
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]),
                CategoryName = Convert.ToString(values[1]),                   
                IsActive = (double)values[2] == 1 ? true : false
            };
            categoryList.Add(category);
        }
    }

    private class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If we execute above code, Foreach method finishes in 56ms while linq one takes 101ms ( for 1000 records).
So Foreach method is better to use.
Source:[Ways to Convert Datatable to List in C# (with performance test example)](https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-/ways-to-convert-datatable-to-list-in-c-with-performance-test/93)

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me:** 
Need at least .Net Framework 3.5,
*Code below displays DataRow turned to Generic.IEnumerable, comboBox1 has been used for a better illustration.*

```
using System.Linq;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
dt = myClass.myMethod();                 
List<object> list = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable() select (row["name"])).ToList();
comboBox1.DataSource = list;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGz6P.png)

```
public class ModelUser
{
    #region Model

    private string _username;
    private string _userpassword;
    private string _useremail;
    private int _userid;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public int userid
    {
        set { _userid = value; }
        get { return _userid; }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>

    public string username
    {
        set { _username = value; }
        get { return _username; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string useremail
    {
        set { _useremail = value; }
        get { return _useremail; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string userpassword
    {
        set { _userpassword = value; }
        get { return _userpassword; }
    }
    #endregion Model
}

public List<ModelUser> DataTableToList(DataTable dt)
{
    List<ModelUser> modelList = new List<ModelUser>();
    int rowsCount = dt.Rows.Count;
    if (rowsCount > 0)
    {
        ModelUser model;
        for (int n = 0; n < rowsCount; n++)
        {
            model = new ModelUser();

            model.userid = (int)dt.Rows[n]["userid"];
            model.username = dt.Rows[n]["username"].ToString();
            model.useremail = dt.Rows[n]["useremail"].ToString();
            model.userpassword = dt.Rows[n]["userpassword"].ToString();

            modelList.Add(model);
        }
    }
    return modelList;
}

static DataTable GetTable()
{
    // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("userid", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("username", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("useremail", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("userpassword", typeof(string));

    // Here we add five DataRows.
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Jame", "Jame@hotmail.com", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    table.Rows.Add(50, "luci", "luci@hotmail.com", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    table.Rows.Add(10, "Andrey", "Andrey@hotmail.com", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Michael", "Michael@hotmail.com", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Steven", "Steven@hotmail.com", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    return table;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ModelUser> userList = new List<ModelUser>();

    DataTable dt = GetTable();

    userList = DataTableToList(dt);

    gv.DataSource = userList;
    gv.DataBind();
}[enter image description here][1]
```

```
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic method like that for datatable to generic list

```
public static List<T> DataTableToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new()
{
    try
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();

        foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
        {
            T obj = new T();

            foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                try
                {
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                    {
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Enum.Parse(propertyInfo.PropertyType, row[prop.Name].ToString()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(row[prop.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
                    }                          
                }
                catch
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            list.Add(obj);
        }

        return list;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting `DataTable` to Generic `Dictionary`

```
public static Dictionary<object,IList<dynamic>> DataTable2Dictionary(DataTable dt)
{
    Dictionary<object, IList<dynamic>> dict = new Dictionary<dynamic, IList<dynamic>>();

    foreach(DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        IList<dynamic> ts = dt.AsEnumerable()
                              .Select(r => r.Field<dynamic>(column.ToString()))
                              .ToList();
        dict.Add(column, ts);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Extension :

```
public static class Extensions
{
    #region Convert Datatable To List
    public static IList<T> ToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : new()
    {
        IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();
        IList<T> result = new List<T>();

        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            var item = CreateItemFromRow<T>((DataRow)row, properties);
            result.Add(item);
        }
        return result;
    }
    private static T CreateItemFromRow<T>(DataRow row, IList<PropertyInfo> properties) where T : new()
    {
        T item = new T();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            property.SetValue(item, row[property.Name], null);
        }
        return item;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following two Generic functions

```
private static List<T> ConvertDataTable<T>(DataTable dt)
    {
        List<T> data = new List<T>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            T item = GetItem<T>(row);
            data.Add(item);
        }
        return data;
    }
    private static T GetItem<T>(DataRow dr)
    {

        Type temp = typeof(T);
        T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Table.Columns)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo pro in temp.GetProperties())
            {
                if (pro.Name == column.ColumnName)
                    pro.SetValue(obj, dr[column.ColumnName].ToString(), null);
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

and use it as following

```
List<StudentScanExamsDTO> studentDetails = ConvertDataTable<StudentScanExamsDTO>(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this using Newtonsoft Json:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable);
var YourConvertedDataType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourDataType>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get `List` of values instead of `ItemArray`, do this:

```
List<string> s = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[0].ToString()).ToList();
```

The above assumes that you want list of string values from column 0.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**To assign the DataTable rows to the generic List of class**

```
  List<Candidate> temp = new List<Candidate>();//List that holds the Candidate Class,
    //Note:The Candidate class contains RollNo,Name and Department
    //tb is DataTable
    temp = (from DataRow dr in tb.Rows
                        select new Candidate()
                        {
                            RollNO = Convert.ToInt32(dr["RollNO"]),
                            Name = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                            Department = dr["Department"].ToString(),

                        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert a dataTable into a generic list, here `List<CustomerEntity>`, try this code:

```
List<CustomerEntity> customers = new List<CustomerEntity>();
List<DataRow> rows = dataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList();

rows.ForEach(r =>
    {
        customers.Add(new CustomerEntity()
        {
            Id= r.Field<int>("Id"),
            Name= r.Field<string>("Name"),
            Address= r.Field<string>("Address"),
            Point= r.Field<int>("Point")
        }
    );
    });
```

or

```
List<CustomerEntity> customers = dataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
        .Select(dr => new CustomerEntity
        {
            Id= dr.Field<int>("Id"),
            Name= dr.Field<string>("Name"),
            Address= dr.Field<string>("Address"),
            Point= dr.Field<int>("Point")
        }).ToList();
```