# How to convert typed DataTable into List of Entity?

Tags: c#, entity, strongly-typed-dataset

I need to convert the data of a Typed DataTable to List of my entity. I've Mapped all the fields of entity with field of DataTable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441023/fastest-way-to-convert-datatable-to-generic-list ? Although I should stress that starting from a micro-ORM instead of datatable is more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be by doing it through custom code
Lets suppose you Entity class name is 'MyEnt'

```
 public class MyEnt
    {
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public string Type {get; set;}
     public LoadMyEnt(object [] array)
      {
         this.Name = array[0].ToString();
         this.Type = array[1].ToString();   
      }
    }
```

//for datatable, you could do

```
List<MyEnt> list = new List<MyEnt>();
foreach(DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
  MyEnt obj = new MyEnt();
obj.Load(dr.ItemArray);
list.Add(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would check out [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) which is a great tool that focus on these kind of scenarios.

Also [here](http://house9.blogspot.com/2010/11/automapper-datatable-to-list.html) is guy that have done exactly your scenario.

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert it to generic datatable and then convert that datatable to list.
There are plenty of code snippets available to convert generic datatable to list. Some are:
[How do you convert a DataTable into a generic list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/208532/337294)
[Convert DataTable to List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1427484/337294)
[Fastest way to convert datatable to generic list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441023/337294)

Answer (score 0):

You could write an Extension Method:

```
public static List<TItem> Cast<TItem>(this DataRowCollection drc, Func<DataRow, TItem> converter)
    {
        List<TItem> list= new List<TItem>();
        foreach (DataRow row in drc)
        {
            list.Add(converter(row));
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Wherein converter is e.g. a lambda expression containing the following:

```
item => new YourClass(item)
```

Thanks,

Dennis