# Select and Cast to convert a Generic List into DataRow[]

Tags: c#, linq, casting, dataset

There is a typed DataSet Named DsPerson
And a custom Typed Generic List Named ListPerson

```
DsPerson Ds1Person;

List<Person> ListPerson;
```

Want to do something similar to the code below,

please help me correcting this :

```
 DataTable dtPerson = Ds1Person.Tables["Person"];
 DataRow drPerson = dtPerson.NewRow();

 DsPerson.PersonRow[] updRows = ListPerson.Cast<Person>().Select(row => dtPerson.NewRow()
                      {
                          Nick = row.Nick,
                          Name = row.NameX,
                       }).ToArray();
```

Needed a DataRow Array or a general DataTable made this way.

Not looking for Entities here or any other alternatives because of the code specifications I'm working on.

Any help is really appreciated ...

---

**`More Clarifying :`**

**What Is needed :**

Something Like reversing these :
(Opposite way)

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/441023/fastest-way-to-convert-datatable-to-generic-list

or a cleaner and Linqy way of doing something similar to this :

http://beecy.net/post/2009/05/18/convert-generic-list-to-datatable-using-reflection.aspx

Get the proper **DsPerson.PersonRow[] updRows** 
to use with
adapter.Update(updRows);

**What Is wrong ?**

The Cast - Select Statement have slight errors :
I just knew it should be similar to this, so I'm not sure on the structure of this line of code,

***for now the reported error is :***

*Error  2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'DsPerson.PersonRow[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same should work for a strong typed `DataSet`:

```
DataRow[] updRows = 
    ListPerson.Select(p => dtPerson.Rows.Add(p.Nick, p.Name)).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1, Thanks Tim, I'll try it in minutes, In addition is there any way to map the columns ?  Also shouldn't I use DsPerson.PersonRow or any other typed alternatives ?