# How to convert c# generic list to json using json.net?

Tags: c#, json, generics, list, json.net

I am converting my datatable to c# generic list.

```
 DataTable dt = mydata();
 List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Now how can i convert this `list` to json using json.net? Any suggestion.

Sample of json format should be like this,

```
{"Table" : [{"userid" : "1","name" : "xavyTechnologies","designation" : "",
"phone" : "9999999999","email" : "test@test.com","role" : "Admin","empId" : "",
 "reportingto" : ""},{"userid" : "2","name" : "chendurpandian","designation" :
 "softwaredeveloper","phone" : "9566643707","email" : "chendur.pandia@gmail.com",
 "role" : "Super User","empId" : "1","reportingto" : "xavyTechnologies"},
{"userid" : "3","name" : "sabarinathan","designation" : "marketer","phone" :
"66666666666","email" : "bala3569@gmail.com","role" : "User",
 "empId" : "2","reportingto" : "chendurpandian"}]}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's one example:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("userid");
        table.Columns.Add("phone");
        table.Columns.Add("email");

        table.Rows.Add(new[] { "1", "9999999", "test@test.com" });
        table.Rows.Add(new[] { "2", "1234567", "foo@test.com" });
        table.Rows.Add(new[] { "3", "7654321", "bar@test.com" });

        var query = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                    select new {
                        userid = (string) row["userid"],
                        phone = (string) row["phone"],
                        email = (string) row["email"]            
                    };

        JObject o = JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            Table = query
        });

        Console.WriteLine(o);
    }
}
```

Documentation: [**LINQ to JSON with Json.NET**](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm)

Comment: the example uses linq but i want to use a generic list

Comment: @Pandiya: So just change the `table.AsEnumerable()` bit to `list`. Given that you were using `DataTable` in your example, I thought you wanted a `DataTable` as your original source... otherwise why did you bother with that bit of code?

Answer (score 21):

```
var oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(yourList);
```

Reference:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pini_dayan/archive/2009/03/12/convert-objects-to-json-in-c-using-javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: This does not seems to be working for me, the sJON returns empty {}