# c# to json structure help

Tags: c#, json

I have a list of strings in C# List and need to return a json structure that looks like this:

```
'String1': { name: 'String1' }
```

What is the best and easiest way to achieve this?

Edit: I do not need a serializer, I strictly need help with the structure.  I am using .net mvc JsonResult.

Comment: Look into [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) or [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be valid JSON it should look like this:

```
"String1": { "name": "String1" }
```

If you know that the strings doesn't contain anything that needs encoding (e.g. quotation marks), which is likely if you want to use them as identifiers, you can just do the serialisation yourself:

```
string json =
  "{" +
  String.Join(",", list.Select(s => "\"" + s + "\":{\"name\":\"" + s + "\"}")) +
  "}";
```

where `list` is your list of strings.

Comment: @Victor: This is as easy as it gets. You could use a serialiser instead, but just the code to create the objects to serialise is even more complicated than this, especially as you use dynamic properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` as outlined in this article: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx

Comment: Might be a bit overkill for an object structure this simple, but hey. =D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).  See more examples [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pini_dayan/archive/2009/03/12/convert-objects-to-json-in-c-using-javascriptserializer.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482261/how-to-convert-c-generic-list-to-json-using-json-net).

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = 
     new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(myList);
```

Comment: I need help getting the getting the object setup, not the serializer.  I have updated the question.