# C# List<dictionary> To Json

Tags: c#, json, list, dictionary

I want to convert my List>
 to JSON string. Does anyone know how to achive this in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert c# generic list to json using json.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482261/how-to-convert-c-sharp-generic-list-to-json-using-json-net)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use  [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
List<Dictionary<string, string>> testDictionary = new List<Dictionary<string, string>()>();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testDictionary);
```