# Am I not returning this JSON string correctly?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm trying to grab some values from the database using AJAX, but every time I check firebug, I see the html copy instead.

```
 function foo() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "cssAttempt3.aspx/ConvertDataTabletoString",
                data: {},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(result);
                    //I have tried a bunch of things here.
                    //console.log(response, response[0], response[0].value, 
                    //JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString() %>'), JSON.parse(response), JSON.stringify(response), and the list goes on.
                    //Every single time, Firebug shoots back the html document.
                    //Nothing really stands out in this html document.  No errors.
                    //But time to time, Firebug will say unidentified character
                    //JSON.parse: unexpected character
                    //Line 4
                    //Which can't be right, I'm using Google's jQuery and the console.log below is parsed correctly.
                    //If you look up there, result and response are two different things
                    //But Firebug won't report any error even when I compile that.
                    //I've even typed alert("ASDFSAOF") just to see what happens.  Nothing.
                    //I haven't seen "Fail" either.
                },
                failure: function () {
                    console.log("Fail");
                }
            });
        };

        foo();
        console.log(JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString() %>'));
        //This, which has nothing to do with AJAX, works okay.
        //I've taken from the html document 
    </script>
```

I reedited this, because I do not think it's the JSON.  My apologies for leading everyone that way.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
public partial class cssAttempt3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    // This method is used to convert datatable to json string
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string ConvertDataTabletoString()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=personnet;Integrated Security=Yes;"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT TOP 200 * FROM personnet.dbo.accordionTest", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return serializer.Serialize(rows);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're completely ignoring the `response` and instead `console.log()`ing a server-side value. Why?

Comment: what is console.log(JSON.parse(response)) telling you?

Comment: I mentioned below that I've tried response a couple times.  The JSON.parse was just my latest attempt.  I was using console.log to see just if anything comes up.

Comment: console.log(JSON.parse(response)) is telling me the same thing.  Just shows me my website.

Comment: you also could check the networkstatus in firebug. see if you are receiving data by the server.

Comment: could you please post the output of: console.log(result);

Comment: @user2457009 I'm betting you aren't even returning JSON. Please add an error case `error: function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown ) {
                 alert(errorThrown);
             }`. It will probably say `SyntaxError: JSON.parse`, verifying this.

Comment: That's exactly what it says.

Comment: @user2457009 well, please see my answer on how to build a proper JSON feed. Or post your code on how you are generating yours, because that is the problem.

Comment: @user2457009 - can you double-check that what's being returned isn't an actual HTML page - as MikeSmithDev said, if you don't get actual JSON back but instead are getting for e.g. an error page, or if your "ajax" request is being treated as a plain old HTTP request then you will get back HTML and jQuery's internal json parser *will* choke meaning you *don't* even get your error handler.
Now the fact that you are getting status code 200 hints that it's not an error and is actually your aspx page rendered. Can you try adding `contentType:application/json,charset=utf-8` into the ajax options?

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda weird.  If I include contentType:application/json,charset=utf-8 but exclude dataType: 'json', I'll get the success function... which is now alert(response) so I get my html crammed in a little window.  If I include contentType and include dataType, the error function kicks in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your examples and comments, it's possible your JSON isn't valid. You can validate your output at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). It'd really help if you showed how you were creating your JSON feed at `cssAttempt3.aspx/ConvertDataTabletoString`.

Another problem is that you are using `JSON.parse` instead of `JSON.stringify`.

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fparse) parses a *string* as JSON.

The opposite, [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) accepts a value to convert to a JSON string. Your value (`response`) is already JSON.

```
function foo() {
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'cssAttempt3.aspx/ConvertDataTabletoString',
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function (response) {
             var t = JSON.stringify(response);
             var o = JSON.parse(t); //now this should work. Turns it back into what you get from url response.
             console.log(t);
         },
         failure: function () {
             console.log("Fail");
         },
         error: function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
             console.log(errorThrown); //...its possibly not even JSON response at all!
         }
     });
}
```

As a side not, a more efficient way to create your JSON is is with an ASHX handler... and will only take minor modifications to your code:

Add `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` to your class (you need a reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization` for this to work):

```
[DataContract]
public class MyDataTableClass
{
    [DataMember]
    private string pro;
    [DataMember]
    private string sn;
    [DataMember]
    private string po;
    //etc
```

And then make the ASHX (Right-click your project -> Add New Item -> Generic Handler):

```
public class ConvertDataTabletoString: IHttpHandler
{     
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        List<MyDataTableClass> m = //populate

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer s = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<MyDataTableClass>));
        s.WriteObject(stream, m);
        stream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

then just update your url: `url: 'ConvertDataTabletoString.ashx',`

Comment: I'm new to the concept of ashx.  I've added namespace MyTypes {[DataContract//etc to my cs file and added the ashx file, but lots of errors come up with "The type or namespace could not be found..."

Comment: I verified my JSON at JSONLint.  Aside from the surrounding apostrophes (I tried to exclude them; same results), it's valid.

Comment: You need `using System.Runtime.Serialization`

Comment: Also... you say you verified your JSON, but some you posted is invalid, and in other comments you say the response is bringing back the HTML for your site... so it's unclear what is really happening.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion.  foo()'s response is the html, which sees nothing of JSON.  I made a console.log() without any AJAX which can clearly see and parse the JSON.  I copied and pasted firebug's console.log() into JSONLint and it was invalid due to the apostrophes surrounding it.  Other than the apostrophes, it's valid.  Firebug is both reporting foo() and the console.log() and I want to get foo() working.

Comment: Is JSON.stringify not to create a jsonstring out of an javascript object?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I thought you would like to convert a jsonstring into a javascript array/object....   With json.stringify you create out of a javascript array/object a jsonstring

Comment: @Getu.ch his result from the URL call should be the javascript object, not a string. Why JSON.Parse something that is already in that format?

Comment: @user2457009 added an example in my answer that shows how JSON.parse will work against JSON.stringify... doing so just turns the JSON string back into the equivalent of `response`.

Comment: My post was getting messy, so I formatted it a bit and I do not think it's JSON.  I've added one new detail: Even though I added alert("ASFDASDF") the success function won't do anything.

Comment: @user2457009 so simply having `success: function (response) { alert('nooo');}` doesn't work at all? If that is the case, then I think your response is not JSON at all. What happens when you remove `dataType: 'json',`?

Comment: Does the ashx need any other assembly directives?  Could you show an example of how I'd populate List<MyDataTableClass>?

Comment: @user2457009 [Here is a full code example](http://mikesmithdev.com/blog/fullcalendar-json-feed-httphandler-csharp/)

Comment: I went to study ashx, but I came across an article explaining the different ways to connect to a database and decided to go with Web Services, thus ended up rewriting the C# code.  I'm going to mark your answer as the solution as it pointed me to the article.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure to mark your `ConvertDataTabletoString` method with a `[WebMethod]` or `[ScriptMethod]` attribute?

If you don't, then when you request the page via Ajax, it will just be handled as though you had requested it via a normal HTTP GET request and the actual HTML that the aspx page generates will be returned to you. That's what seems to be happening although of course I could be wrong.

Also I normally prefer to make methods that I want to call via Ajax on an aspx page `static` because this makes it clear that they're not part of the "normal" aspx page (if you are not mixing functionality and this aspx page exists only to service AJAX requests then it's probably ok)

Edit: Forgot to mention, make sure you carefully read the HTML that's showing in firebug - it may actually be a web server error message page indicating that something else entirely is wrong!

Comment: I've added [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] before the code.  I've also looked at the html, but nothing pops out at me.  I don't think there would be anything since I'm doing console.log and alert().

Comment: cool. if you are still getting the problem, can you post up some of the HTML you are seeing in Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

In your success function you pass the response variable. This variable is the store(includes the values) of the response you get from your server.

so try following:

```
    function foo() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "cssAttempt3.aspx/ConvertDataTabletoString",
        data: {},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (response) {

            console.log(response); //change the parse parameter to response
        },
        failure: function () {
            console.log("Fail");
        }
    });
};
```

EDIT:

Try to use jsonp as datatype and log the output without parse it (jsonp parse it for you)

example updated.

EDIT 2:
use [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
List<Dictionary<string, string>> testDictionary = new List<Dictionary<string, string>()>();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testDictionary);
```

credits:
[C# List<dictionary> To Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823455/c-sharp-listdictionary-to-json)

Comment: Marcel suggested that to me earlier and I've gotten the same results.

Comment: Could you please post the firebug output of this?

Comment: I've changed it to jsonp and to console.log(response), but it still posts the html.  I'll post the C# code and hope it provides some insight.

Comment: It's the same results, but I don't think I did it right.  I installed Json.net and applied said changes (my question post reflects this under ATTEMPT:).  Could you see it?

Comment: Is it possible for to post the return string of the c# application instead of the ajax return? Is this json string then correct?