# Unable to parse JSON returned by JQuery ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I am calling a method using JQuery ajax given below

```
$.post('../User/GetCountry',
        {
            zone: 1
        },
        function (data) {
            alert(data);
            alert(data["Countries"]);
        }, "json").fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert(textStatus);
        });
```

C# code

```
public static string GetCountry()
    {
        var result = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Countries.GetAll());
        return result;
    }
```

Now when I debug my code on server side i see the below result which is perfect json according to me

```
[{"Id":4,"Name":"France"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Germany"}]
```

But in javascript I am getting the json as

```
[[object Object],[object Object]]
```

Can anyone please let me know what I am missing here

**SOLVED USING
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
var jsonParse = JSON.parse(jsonData);**

Comment: it is just telling you that this is an array of objects :) which is true

Comment: use `console.log(data)` instead. alert() is going to try and stringify things for you, which means the objecst will just be `object Object`.

Comment: You are getting back an array of objects. Try using [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to deserialize the array. It'll be much easier this way!

Comment: @icemanind it already is deserialized, hence the [object Object] he is seeing.

Comment: @Raj Kumar, are you using asp.net page method?

Comment: Yes i am using asp.net pages

Comment: Solved using var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
                var jsonParse = JSON.parse(jsonData);

Comment: @RajKumar funny, that's something I just posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116385/am-i-not-returning-this-json-string-correctly/19116932#19116932 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this after searching bit more

```
$.post('../User/GetCountry',
    {
        zone: 1
    },
    function (data) {
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data); 
        var jsonParse = JSON.parse(jsonData);
        }, "json").fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(textStatus);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a few issues with your code. First, despite the fact that you're passing a parameter `zone` to the web service method the method itself doesn't receive this parameter. Second, if you want to return JSON don't use the return type string. Use `JSONResult`. This will allow you to remove the static keyword as well. I'd recommend changing your method like so:

```
public JSONResult GetCountry(int? zone)
{
    // ...
}
```

There are two final changes you should make. The first is to use ASP.Net MVC's built in `Json()` method to handle serialization of your object. The second is that you should always project your data layer results even if they happen to already be in the structure you want to use. This way if you change your data layer object in a way that breaks the service you'll get a compile error instead of a run time exception.

```
return Json(from c in Countries.GetAll() select new { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name })
```

I'd also recommend avoiding using `$.get` or `$.post` as they abstract away settings that can be useful when access web services. If you want to shorthand it I'd recommend wrapping the `$.ajax` call in your own function. You're also going to want to think about standardizing your web service responses. Your web service is a protocol of sorts and as such it benefits from having a well defined header. For a more in-depth explanation take a look here: [Introduction to MVC Service Based Web Applications](http://www.netortech.com/Blog/Entry/17/MVC-Service-Based-Web-Applications---Part-I---Introduction)

Comment: I am using asp.net not MVC

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
alert(data[0].Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../User/GetCountry',
    data: {
        zone: 1
    },
    success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

works good for me. You need to make sure you're sending a content-type of "application/json", preferably using the `Json()` helper method in `Controller`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using JSON.parse():

```
$.post('../User/GetCountry',
        {
            zone: 1
        },
        function (data) {
            data=JSON.parse(data)

            alert(data["Countries"][0].Name);
        }, "json").fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert(textStatus);
        });
```