# Convert DataTable to IEnumerable<T> in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I need to generate an 'IEnumerable from a DataTable that I receive as an input from another system.  The following code worked in ASP.NET 4.6.1.

```
public static IEnumerable<UserAssignmentDto> StaffAssignmentsUsingStoredProcedure(System.Data.DataTable dataTable)
    {
        var data = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
            new UserAssignmentDto
            {
                Id = ((string)row["AssignmentNumber"]),
                Position = (string) row["EsrPositionTitle"],

            });

        return data;
    }
```

However, 'DataTable' no longer contains a definition for 'AsEnumerable' in ASP.NET Core 2.0.

What would be the most efficient way to generate the 'IEnumerable' that I need?

Comment: Use a for loop and iterate through the DataTable rows and hydrate the IEnumerable<UserAssignmentDto>

Comment: Can you show me what you mean by hydrate?

Comment: Cant you just go and say ``dataTable.Rows.Select(...);`` ? If the select "item" is an object, you could add OfType<> ``dataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(...);``

Comment: You can also use cast: `dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(...)`. Is this better or worse than OfType?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most efficient things you can do is write the code for the iteration yourself, using a for loop instead of LINQ, just iterate over the DataTable rows and build/hydrate the `IEnumerable<UserAssignmentDto>` method return value "by hand".

Since there DataTable does not implement an Enumerator in .NET Core 2.0 you will need to use a "regular" `for` loop to iterate over the rows. You cannot use `foreach` because DataTable has not implemented IEnumerable in .NET Core 2.0.

```
public static IEnumerable<UserAssignmentDto> StaffAssignmentsUsingStoredProcedure(System.Data.DataTable dataTable)
{
    var retList = new List<UserAssignmentDto>();

    for(int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
          var row = dataTable.Rows[i];

          var temp = new UserAssignmentDto(){
              Id = row["AssignmentNumber"],
              Position = row["EsrPositionTitle"]
          };

          retList.Add(temp);     
    }

    return retList;
}
```

Comment: I think the List<UserAssignmentDto> needs to be initialized.  Also, I am getting the error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'DataTable' because 'DataTable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: @RoddyBalkan ok I updated my answer to fix that error

Comment: @RoddyBalkan List<UserAssignmentDto> is initialized already, this line of code: var retList = List<UserAssignmentDto>();

Comment: @RoddyBalkan Sorry I forgot the new keyword for initializing List<UserAssignmentDto>, please note, you cannot use foreach because DataTable has not implemented GetEnumerator in .NET Core 2.0

Answer (score 14):

The correct nuget package for .net core 2 is `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`

Comment: This nuget was introduced later; but really helpful as we can use like .net framework. :)

Answer (score 12):

Here is a generic AsEnumerable extension function to mimic what the classic AsEnumerable() did, return an Enumerable collection of DataRows from a DataTable. Can be useful for someone that wishes to mimimize the amount of refactoring needed when porting their code to .net core.

```
    public static IEnumerable<DataRow> AsEnumerable(this DataTable table)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            yield return table.Rows[i];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

Not about most efficient but for an alternative, you can use the `Select` method:

```
DataRow[] rows= dataTable.Select();
```

And now you have an IEnumerable of rows. 
This method may help someone:

```
public static List<T> ConvertDataTableToGenericList<T>(DataTable dt)
{
     var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
            .Select(c => c.ColumnName)
            .ToList();

     var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
     DataRow[] rows= dt.Select();
     return rows.Select(row =>
     {
          var objT = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
          foreach (var pro in properties)
          {
              if (columnNames.Contains(pro.Name))
                   pro.SetValue(objT, row[pro.Name]);
          }

          return objT;
     }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`AsEnumerable()` does exist in .NET Core 2.0, you just need to add a reference to `System.Data.DataExtensions` as mentioned in the answer to a similar question.
[LINQ to DataSet, DataTable.AsEnumerable() not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949302/linq-to-dataset-datatable-asenumerable-not-recognized)

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency depends on use case. The Brians answer is good if you need the whole result. It can be improved, by preallocating capacity for List to avoid resizing or changing to Array, but generally it is good. I would rather return List or Array to more explicitely show what it does, but that is my personal choice. It conserves state of DataTable at the moment it is called, which may be good or bad depending on what you need.

If there is a chance you would not need all items or maybe you would not enumerate the IEnumerable at all, it may be more efficient to construct real enumerator:

```
public static IEnumerable<UserAssignmentDto> StaffAssignmentsUsingStoredProcedure(System.Data.DataTable dataTable)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable)
            {
               yield return new UserAssignmentDto()
                {
                    Id = row["AssignmentNumber"],
                    Position = row["EsrPositionTitle"]
                };               
            }
        }
```

But it is not the fastest option still. You may avoid allocating new object every time you yield. You can return the same object every time, just set properties accordingly. It has the obvious drawback that you can not store objects from such IEnumerable for future use, but sometimes you do not need that.

```
public static IEnumerable<UserAssignmentDto> StaffAssignmentsUsingStoredProcedure(System.Data.DataTable dataTable)
        {
            UserAssignmentDto ret = new UserAssignmentDto();
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable)
            {
                ret.Id = row["AssignmentNumber"];
                ret.Position = row["EsrPositionTitle"];
                yield return ret;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `myDataTable.Select();` it returns an array of all DataRow