# return data as SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on an ASP.NET project. I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which returns a list of data to show in a chart. This stored procedure works fine. I need the return data to be a `SqlDataReader` object to pass into the `Chart.DataBindTable`.

I call the stored procedure like this:

```
string spName = "spFetchDetails";
DbCommand dbCommand = this.ObjDatabase.GetStoredProcCommand(spName);
this.ObjDatabase.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@Company", DbType.Int32, Company);
this.ObjDatabase.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@Title", DbType.String, Title);
this.ObjDatabase.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@DateRange", DbType.String, DateRange);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = this.ObjDatabase.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand).Tables[0];
```

Here the code is returning the stored procedure result as a `DataTable`, I want to call `ExecuteReader()` method, but I am not sure how to do that.

```
Chart.DataBindTable(dt, "Example");
```

This is the code to render the chart.

Below is how I do in another chart and it is working.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
  "Select ai.ItemDescription, ai.ItemRate, los.sellingprice, los.mrp from aitem ai inner join losShopItemShipmentDetail los on los.itemid = ai.itemid", con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Chart.DataBindTable(rdr, "ItemDescription");
```

How do I call a stored procedure this way? or is there a way to pass the DataTable into DataBindTable function?

```
public void DataBindTable (System.Collections.IEnumerable dataSource, string xField);
```

Comment: Passing around a `SqlDataReader` as "data" is not a good idea - it's much better to have a `DataTable` or a `List<T>` or something that contains **only** the data - not the whole overhead of an opened `SqlDataReader` .....

Comment: then how to pass datatable into DataBindTable

Comment: Well - check the **documentation** for that `Chart` component of yours - I'm almost convinced there **must be** a different way to provide the data than by passing in a `SqlDataReader`  (and if not: find a better chart component...)

Comment: This chart component? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart.databindtable?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @CaiusJard yes it is

Answer (score 1):

You could try this (sample code to visualise how to use it):

```
Chart c = new Chart();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
c.DataBindTable(dt.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: Note that if you're using .net core then AsEnumerable may not be available without referencing an extension - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable?view=netframework-4.8 and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900952/convert-datatable-to-ienumerablet-in-asp-net-core-2-0

Answer (score 0):

you can call the stored procedure as below.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("<SqlProcedureName>", con)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

But in place of assigning datareader to chart control. Find another way to set the data only