# How do you convert a DataSet/DataTable into a generic list of certain type?

Tags: c#, generics, dataset

I have looked at the [answered topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208532/how-do-you-convert-a-datatable-into-a-generic-list) with the answer:
List list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();

However, what if wanted to convert to a list of some entity type? For instance, I have an entity class Property:

```
public class Property
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Chain { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Street2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string FAX { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Airport { get; set; }
    }
```

I have to work with an Oracle SP that returns a DataSet. What I want to do is convert the DataSet (or a DataTable) into a List

DataSet ds = ("call SP");
   List = ds.something;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consider LINQ in this case.

```
var list = (from dr in dt.AsEnumerable()
           select new Property { .... }).ToList();
```

Creates the List as result.

Edit : Made the first sentence mild.

Comment: Yaah... Sorry, I meant to say LINQ could be a choice in this. :)

Comment: What do the 3 dots symbolize? Is it an anonymous type and I have to put in every field? Could you flesh this out> Thanks!

Comment: Also, what if it's a DataSet?

Comment: @Sam Gentile ~ DataSet is a collection of DataTable with some extra information. You can either `foreach (DataTable dt in ds)` or you can specify each by index `ds.Tables[i]`

Comment: @Sam, yes you need to replace the 3 dots with the Property Setters like new Property { Id=dr[0].ToString(), Chain = dr[1].ToString()...}
If it is a dataset, you will probably have enumeration of tables. Do you mean you need to put contents of each tables in the same list ?

Comment: Yes, I may need to put contents of each table in the same list

Comment: Is it dr in { Id=dr[0].ToString(), Chain = dr[1].ToString()...}  or ItemArray[0]. Doesn't ItemArray[i] have the value?

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note.  I've gone down this path before and have found that most of the time I didn't need some sort of entity class wrapper around the datatable.  Instead, the normal rows/columns access of the datatable itself was just fine.  It saved processing time and memory consumption by just passing the table around.

Typically speaking if I'm pulling the data from a proc for display, I leave it in a table.  However, if I have a class which includes additional functionality beyond just holding data, then I might convert the datatable into a list/collection of objects.

On the flip side if data is coming back from the browser, then I'll populate an object whose class definition has all of the associated validation tied in prior to storing in the database.

The point is, unless the entity class is going to give you something you don't already have then I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is in VB, you may be able to convert it to C# and use it:

> How to convert dataset or dbreader to
>   List(of T) or BindingList(Of T) using
>   mapping
>
> http://prglog.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-convert-listof-t-or.html

It looks like it uses reflection and will work with any type.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the LINQ `Select()` method

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable
var list = dt.Rows.Select(row => new Propert
{
SomeProperty = row["columnName"],//etc...
}).ToList();
```

Comment: seem to be having a little trouble with the code viewer today :-P

Comment: What is EnumerableDataRowList? Is it List<Property> in my case or something defined by the framework?

Comment: my apologies, that's a custom class we use. You should be able to do the same thing with the by just putting the select on the dt.Rows, I'll fix my example in a sec

Comment: I found your custom class here on Code Project http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQGroupByMultipleColumn.aspx?display=Print

Comment: Guess it's not so custom after all :)