# LINQ: DataTable to List

Tags: c#, linq

How to achieve this below datatable to a generic list conversion ?

I am trying this:

```
List<Emp> lstEmp= new List<Emp>(from prod in MyDatatable.AsEnumerable<Emp>() select prod);
```

Comment: [How do you convert a DataTable into a generic list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208532/how-do-you-convert-a-datatable-into-a-generic-list)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: but Jon Skeets answer does not answer this question. OP wants to initialite a custom class from the `DataRow` and create a `List` of it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Not the Jons answer... there are other answers which does this!

Answer (score 3):

```
var empList = MyDatatable.AsEnumerable().Select( row => 
   new Emp
   {
       Name= row.Field<string>("Name") // set the properties accordingly 
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: I do not want to do this : Name= row["Name"].ToString()..Any possibility for direct cast ?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
List<Emp> target = dt.AsEnumerable()
     .Select(row => new Emp
     {
         Name = row.Field<string>("Name")
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: Actually does it really require to specify every field. I want to skip this if LINQ can do this. Just to avoiding this for every field : Name= row.Field<string>("Name") OR Name = String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field<string>(1))...

Comment: you can use filed name too, instead of (1).