# Error while converting DataTable to List<T> in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert `DataTable` into generic list `List<T>`, I am getting this error :

> cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a
>   delegate type

I have gone through several threads posted here on SO regarding this, most of them suggested using `Entity` and `Linq namespaces`, but still I am getting same error.

Here is my code:

```
DataTable csvData = GetDataTableFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);

List<MyClass> lst = new List<MyClass>();
lst = (from l in csvData
      select new MyClass // getting red line under select
      {
       Address_1 = l.Address_1,
       //total of 29 columns
       Title = l.Title,
       Town_of_Birth = l.Town_of_Birth
      }).ToList();
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/208683/4180382

Comment: check answer that might help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AsEnumerable()` extension method inside your linq query to get collection of `DataRow`'s:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}


public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("MyProperty", typeof(int));
    table.Rows.Add(1);
    table.Rows.Add(2);
    table.Rows.Add(3);

    List<MyClass> result = (from t in table.AsEnumerable()
                            select new MyClass
                            {
                                MyProperty = t.Field<int>("MyProperty")
                            }).ToList();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

for generic solution , you can try like as below by making use of generics

```
lst = (from dataRow in csvData.AsEnumerable()
          select Converter<MyClass>.Fill(dataRow)).ToList();

class Converter<T>
    {
        public static T Fill(DataRow Row)
        {

          Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);
         object retval = Activator.CreateInstance(typeParameterType);

            Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> props = new Dictionary<string,PropertyInfo>();
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in retval.GetType().GetProperties())
                props.Add(p.Name, p);
            foreach (DataColumn col in Row.Table.Columns)
            {
                string name = col.ColumnName;
                if (Row[name] != DBNull.Value && props.ContainsKey(name))
                {
                    object item = Row[name];
                    PropertyInfo p = props[name];
                    if (p.PropertyType != col.DataType)
                        item = Convert.ChangeType(item, p.PropertyType);
                    p.SetValue(LogicObject, item, null);
                }
            }
        return (T)retval ;
        }
    }
```

---

you need to do like this , make use of `AsEnumerable`

```
lst = (from dataRow in csvData.AsEnumerable()
      select new MyClass // getting red line under select
      {
       Address_1 = Convert.ToString(dataRow["Address_1"]),
       //total of 29 columns
       Title = Convert.ToString(dataRow["Title"]),
       Town_of_Birth = Convert.ToString(dataRow["Town_of_Birth"])
      }).ToList();
```

when you are reading value of `dataRow` take care of null if some columns going to return null value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Select() method also to enumerate in Lamda, as below:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
var x = from a in dt.Select() where a.HasErrors == false select new Test { MyProperty = a.ItemArray.Count() };
```