# SQL Server Database table to REST web service

Tags: azure, rest

Is there an Azure service to expose the database table to REST API?

I have a table in SQL Server and I want to expose that table via REST API without having to manage any infra or authentication

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-open-data-protocol-odata-and-sql-azure/

Answer (score 0):

No SQL server does not have a REST api directly, But you can build an OData service with [`ASP.NET Web API and Entity Framework.`](http://odata.github.io/RESTier/)

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class based on the table fields and on getting the table data convert it to List and response it.

To Convert DataTable to List use the link:
[Found in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208532/how-do-you-convert-a-datatable-into-a-generic-list/24588210#24588210)