# How can I convert a Datable to a List<T> when class properties match table columns without using a for loop?

Tags: c#, datatable

What's the fastest way to convert a DataTable with matching class properties to a List?

Comment: Why "without using a for loop"? What if that's the fastest way? Why are you manually converting a DataTable to a List<T>? is it always a List<T>, or do you know some concrete type already? Stack Overflow isn't a coding service - we're not here to compete at writing the fastest code to do particular tasks. Instead, you should make your own attempt to do what you want. If you try it and it doesn't work, then you could share a [mcve] with us and clearly explain what you're doing and we can help fix it.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29625894/5509738) work for you

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to write explicit code to create new objects of the class and assign the properties from the corresponding columns directly, that is specific to the class and `DataTable` and returning a `List<T>`.

A fairly slow way is to use Reflection to gather the public properties of the class and assign the corresponding column values to new objects created in that way. However, this is very generic in that it will work with any type without any specialization required.

A combination of the two could probably be created using the C# Source Generator feature, but I don't happen to have that written or lying around. This could allow you to have a somewhat faster method written for you at compile time for any class. It would still have to use runtime lookups for the `DataTable` since it can't (necessarily) know the columns at compile time.

Here is the generic method:

```
public static class DataTableExt {
    public static Action<object, object> SetValueFunc(this MemberInfo member) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.SetValue;
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.SetValue;
            case MethodInfo mi:
                return (destObject, value) => mi.Invoke(destObject, new object[] { value });
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or MethodInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }
    public static void SetValue(this MemberInfo member, object destObject, object value) => member.SetValueFunc()(destObject, value);

    public static bool GetCanWrite(this MemberInfo member) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return true;
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.CanWrite;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be if type FieldInfo or PropertyInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }

    public static List<MemberInfo> GetPropertiesOrFields(this Type t, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
        t.GetMembers(bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field || mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).ToList();

    public static IEnumerable<T> ToIEnumerable<T>(this DataTable dt) where T : new() {
        var props = typeof(T).GetPropertiesOrFields()
                             .Where(mi => dt.Columns.Contains(mi.Name) && mi.GetCanWrite())
                             .ToList();
        foreach (var row in dt.AsEnumerable()) {
            var aT = new T();
            foreach (var p in props)
                p.SetValue(aT, row[p.Name]);
            yield return aT;
        }
    }
}
```

Which you would use like

```
var ans = dt.ToIEnumerable<MyClass>().ToList();
```